# Big-O complexity in a loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

If you had an algorithm with a loop that executed n steps the first time through,then n − 2 the second time, n − 4 the next time, and kept repeating until the last time through the loop it executed 2 steps, what would be the complexity measure of this loop?

I believe this exhibits O(n^2) complexity, as the number of steps not being executed increases quadratically. I am having a hard time visualizing such the loop itself, which makes me less confident about my answer.

Any kind of help/second opinion is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hint : `1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2 = n²/2 + n/2 = O(n²)`.

Comment: And `n + n-2 + n-4 + ... 2 = n²/4 + n/2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the complexity is *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*. This is because what you describe is an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression):

*(n - 2) + (n - 4) + ... + 2* (or an odd number at the end)

(which is, obviously, *2 + 4 + 6 + ... + (n - 2)* or the odd-beginning equivalent, BTW).

Using the [formula for the sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), it is the average of the first and last elements, times the number of elements. Each of these terms is *Θ(n)*, and their product is *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*.